# c++ + opengl in visualstudio

Tags: c++, opengl

i hope you can help me why i get this errors.

> ```
> glm::mat4 buildFrustum( float phiInDegree, float aspectRatio, float near, float far) {
>
>     glm::mat4 fm;
>
>
>     float phiHalfInRadians = 0.5*phiInDegree * (M_PI/180.0);
>     float t = near * tan( phiHalfInRadians );
>     float b = -t;
>     float left = b*aspectRatio;
>     float right = t*aspectRatio;
>
>
>
>     fm[0][0] = (2*near) / (right-left);
>     .......
> ```

At

> float t = near * tan( phiHalfInRadians );
>   i get the error "the operator from "*" must be a pointer"

At

> fm[0][0] = (2*near) / (right-left);

i geht the error "define near"

but i define near in my function...

Comment: I'm afraid `near` and `far` are handled as keywords by VS. Try naming them `near_` and `far_`.